# Wordpress 4.4.4 wp_update_comment bug on column 'comment_post_ID'?

Tags: php, wordpress, debugging

I had to create a custom plugin for a client that moved comments from a post to another post. My wordpress version is 4.4.4. What i've noticed is that wp_update_comment doesn't work properly( at least for wp 4.4.4). For example if is called like that:

```
wp_update_comment(array(
   'comment_ID'=>$comment_id,
   'comment_parent'=>$parent_comment_id,
   'comment_post_ID'=>$to_post_id
));
```

It will update column **comment_post_ID** in wp_comments for ALL comments to 0.

If is called like that:

```
wp_update_comment(array(
   'comment_ID'=>$comment_id,
   'comment_parent'=>$parent_comment_id
));
```

It will work properly. So the problem occurs only when **comment_post_ID** column has to be updated.

**My question is** if this is a known bug, and if has been fixed in the newest versions? OR i am using this function in the wrong way?

I couldn't find anything related to this, only this: [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25321251/wordpress-wp-update-comment-function-not-working)

But this isn't related to this issue.

**Thank you.**